# Running Oculus Unity Sample Framework

Tags: unity-game-engine, oculus

Are there some pre-requisites to running the Oculus Sample Framework in Unity?  I start with a new project, add the package from the store, and that's as far as I get.  51 compiler errors, mainly relating to missing OVR* namespaces.

Also "AssetImporter is referencing an asset from the previous import. This should not happen.".  I thought the idea was that a sample framework would just work?

I'm running Unity 2018.2.11f1.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I needed to install the "Oculus Integration" package too and now it compiles.